# DoGet with multiple parameters not being recognized

Tags: http, google-apps-script, google-sheets, lua

I'm currently trying to connect a Lua Script with a GS WebApp. The connection is working but due to my lack of knowledge in GScripting I'm not sure why it isn't saving my data correctly.

In the Lua side I'm just passing in a hard-code a random name and simple numerical userid.

```
local HttpService = game:GetService("HttpService")
local scriptID = scriptlink
local WebApp 

local function updateSpreadSheet ()
    
    local playerData = (scriptID .. "?userid=123&name:Jhon Smith")
    WebApp = HttpService:GetAsync(playerData)
end

do 
    updateSpreadSheet()
end
```

On the Google Script side i'm only saving the data on the last row and then add the value of the userid and the name.

```
function doGet(e) {
  console.log(e)
 // console.log(f)
  callName(e.parameter.userid,e.parameter.name);
}

function callName(userid,name) {
  // Get the last Row and add the name provided
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1,1).setValues([userid],[name]);
}
```

However, the only data the script is saving is the name, bypassing the the `userid` for reasons I have yet to discover.

Comment: This should be `userid=123&name=Jhon Smith")` not `userid=123&name:Jhon Smith")`

Comment: I changed in a hurry couse included my real name, but it's = on the Lua Script, that's why is saving the name correctly, however the userid IS with the = sign but it's not saving it.

Comment: what does `console.log(e)` log?

Comment: That's the thing. Nothing. To be precisely, there is something wrong with my logs it's says: "Waiting for logs, please wait"
And i'm currently waiting for 26 minutes.

Comment: See at view>executions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setValues() requires a 2D array and range dimensions should correspond to that array. The script is only getting 1 x 1 range and setValues argument is not a 2D array. Fix the syntax or use `appendRow`

```
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1,1,1,2).setValues([[userid,name]]);
//or
sheet.appendRow([userid,name])
```

#### References:

- [appendRow](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object))

Comment: Hey, thanks for the appendRow, function, I tried to find it (something like that) however it's on the same situation, it's saving only the name.

Comment: @Gui Republish a "new" version of the app and try

Comment: Nope, still just the name

Comment: Did you  create a new version  and republish the webapp?

Comment: Yeah, when you asked for the first time, my nope was that still showing the same error.

Comment: Due to the log error I created a new spreadsheet and just copied and pasted the code and it worked. I think it was the appendRow.

However, I'm gonna enjoy this chance to ask a aditional information. How do you add information on a existent line on GS?

Comment: @Gui Better to ask a new question.But you basically get the coordinates of the range and setValues().( The first option in my answer)